# Calculations in table based on variable names in matlab

Tags: matlab, function

I am trying to find a better solution to calculation using data stored in table. I have a large table with many variables (100+) from which I select smaller sub-table with only two observations and their difference for smaller selection of variables. Thus, the resulting table looks for example similarly to this:

```
                 air         bbs          bri
              _________    ________    _________
test1          12.451         0.549       3.6987
test2            10.2          0.47         3.99
diff            2.251      0.078999     -0.29132
```

Now, I need to multiply the ‘diff’ row with various coefficients that differ between variables. I can get the same result with the following code:

```
T(4,:) = array2table([T.air(3)*0.2*0.25, T.bbs(3)*0.1*0.25, T.bri(3)*0.7*0.6/2]);
```

However, I need more flexible solution since the selection of variables will differ between applications. I was thinking that better solution might be using either varfun or rowfun and speficic function that would assign correct coefficients/equations based on variable names:

```
T(4,:) = varfun(@func, T(3,:), 'InputVariables', {'air' 'bbs' 'bri'});
```

or

```
T(4,:) = rowfun(@func, T(3,:), 'OutputVariableNames', T.Properties.VariableNames);
```

However, the current solution I have is similarly inflexible as the basic calculation above:

```
 function [air_out, bbs_out, bri_out] = func(air, bbs, bri)
 air_out = air*0.2*0.25;
 bbs_out = bbs*0.1*0.25;
 bri_out = bri*0.7*0.6/2;
```

since I need to define every input/output variable. What I need is to assign in the function coefficients/equations for every variable and the ability of the function to apply it only to the variables that are present in the specific sub-table.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I do not understand your question actually. Is the problem displaying a table or selecting the right values based on a string?

Comment: Store variables in a cell and use `cellfun`? `for varI = 1:nVar, test{varI} = ...;end`? Or is `test` only a dumy name which you use in your example. This approach become annoying if the variables are called something like `x, y, dist, E, P,...`.

Comment: The problem is selecting the right values based on a string (variable name) and apply them to the correct row and said variables thus creating a new row.

Comment: In the end, the solution turned out to be quite different but simple. I just stored the coefficients in separate table and used intersect to find the correct values to use in the calculations.